# Sass issue when i use the --watch parameter

Tags: sass

When i execute the line

```
$sass --watch sass/views.scss:views.css
```

i get the following message

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > >       NameError: uninitialized constant Listen::MultiListener
> > >       Use --trace for backtrace.

As you can say the process stops immediately and the watch option doesn't work.

What's the problem here ?? I have installed the Ruby 2.0.0-p0 version.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** (--trace)

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > >       /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:266:in `watch': uninitialized constant Listen::MultiListener (NameError)
> > >
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/plugin.rb:107:in`method_missing'
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/exec.rb:452:in `watch_or_update'
> > >
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/exec.rb:315:in`process_result'
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
> > >
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in`parse!'
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.8/bin/sass:9:in `<top (required)>'
> > >
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/sass:23:in`load'
> > >           from /home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/sass:23:in `'

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.x - tried that already?

Comment: I don't think Sass is supposed to work run with Ruby 2.0

Comment: @cimmanon i'm think that too. But Rails 4 is ready (highly recommendable) to work with Ruby 2.0, and it use Sass right. So, what's the trick.

Comment: @jcadiz could you run `$sass --watch sass/views.scss:views.css --trace` to be able to see the full trace?

Answer (score 12):

I tried these answers and none worked, so i did some more research. [Apparently](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/719#issuecomment-17371683), the problem is with the `listen` gem that SASS is using. Sass is only compatible with listen 0.7.

I was able to get it working by running the following two commands (as root):

```
gem uninstall listen
gem install listen -v 0.7.3
```

Comment: It's possible that SASS only works _in multi-file watch mode_ with that version. It will still work with later versions if only watching a single file.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. You just need to run the command in sudo mode.

```
sudo sass --watch sass/views.scss:views.css
```

Comment: If you installed ruby-sass, you can uninstall ruby-sass and install sass using gem

Comment: I'm glad that works but running things in sudo mode that really don't need root permissions isn't a good habit to get into... Better to solve the actual problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by uninstalling the original sass I had installed using apt-get (ruby-sass) and reinstalled using gem

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?  The accepted answer already acknowledged that it was a versioning problem.

Comment: @cimmanon just upvoted jason-pascoe 's  answer because it helped me solve my problem. Merci!

Comment: Yes it was a versioning issue, but I wrote how I fixed it.

Comment: @cimmanon: it adds value to the answer to all of us using a Debian-based distribution. I, too, had installed ruby via apt-get but it turns out one has to install it via gem to solve the versioning issue. Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 2):

Well i fix my problem updating the sass gem to the latest version (3.2.9). I think that this update provide better compatibility with Ruby 2.0.0 when using he --watch parameter.
Everything works great now.

Comment: I am glad to hear so @jcadiz, always have a look on [the rubygems website](http://rubygems.org) before adding them to your `Gemfile`