# Sass --watch throwing the error "NameError: uninitialized constant Listen::Listener"

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, sass

I'm running;

```
sass --watch --style compressed --sourcemap css/sass:css
```

And I'm getting;

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Listen::Listener
```

Running it with --trace gives me;

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:308:in `create_listener': uninitialized constant Listen::Listener (NameError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:233:in `watch'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `send'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `method_missing'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/exec.rb:509:in `watch_or_update'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/exec.rb:346:in `process_result'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/exec.rb:43:in `parse'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/../lib/sass/exec.rb:22:in `parse!'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/sass:13
from /usr/bin/sass:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/sass:19
```

I'm having difficulty working out how to troubleshoot this; does it look to be an error within my SCSS files and how I combine them, or a problem with my sass gem / installation?

Edit: Version details

```
Sass 3.3.0.rc.3 (Maptastic Maple)
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Try updating your sass to the latest version, as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795695/sass-issue-when-i-use-the-watch-parameter

Comment: @mcabrams - thanks, but running the latest possible - this is actually a pre-release to get --sourcemap; Sass 3.3.0.rc.3 (Maptastic Maple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be a known [problem with RC3 of Sass 3.3](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1110), which I'm trying to use for Sourcemaps support. I use an earlier RC on another box and it works correctly, so tried installing RC2 here and it solves the issue.

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
...
sudo gem install sass -v 3.3.0.rc.2
```