# Error on using scss CLI with --watch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to watch for a .scss file, using `scss` command.
When I run

```
scss scss/main.scss:public/css/main.css --watch
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Listen::MultiListener
```

and here is the result of the command with and `--trace` parameter:

```
masious@ubuntu:~/Desktop/laravel$ sudo scss scss/main.scss:public/css/main.css --watch --trace
```

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > >       /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:250:in `watch': uninitialized constant Listen::MultiListener (NameError)
> > >           from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/plugin.rb:107:in`method_missing'
> > >           from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec.rb:459:in `watch_or_update'
> > >           from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec.rb:326:in`process_result'
> > >           from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
> > >           from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec.rb:21:in`parse!'
> > >           from /usr/bin/scss:8:in `'

Comment: Answer is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795695/sass-issue-when-i-use-the-watch-parameter